# css - common box-shadow for multiple divs without parent

Tags: css

Is there a way to style a row of divs with multiple box-shadows so they look like the box-shadow is on wrapping element?
Due to 3rd party lib limitation I cannot put a box-shadow on a parent element.
Here is the snippet - I cannot really get rid of the spaces between box-shadows.

```css
.container {
  /* THIS ELEMENT CANNOT HAVE BOX-SHADOW*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 160px;
  height: 90px;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 5px -5px #333, 0 5px 5px -5px #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could apply the shadow to `container::before` and keep the pseudoelement under the children.

```css
.container {
   /* THIS ELEMENT CANNOT HAVE BOX-SHADOW */
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   position: relative;
   width: max-content; 
}

.container::before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 0;
   top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
   box-shadow: 0 -5px 5px -5px #333, 0 5px 5px -5px #333;
 
 }

  
.child {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 160px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is just brilliant! Thanks a lot!